# File Handling in Java Programming

Tags: java, file-handling

I am a beginner in programming.

I am trying to read the first word of every line from a file, and I want to write all of the first words to another file.

I have done the following code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class ReadWord
 {
   public static void main(String args[])
     {
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;
    int count = 0;
    InputStream fis = null;

    try
    {
        fis = new FileInputStream("D:/Android/WorkSpace10-1/FileHandling.Java/src/123.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        while((line = br.readLine())!=  null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            String result[] = line.split(",");
            while(line!=",")
            {                   
              System.out.println(result);               
            }               
        }               
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    finally
    {
        try
        {
            fis.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ie)
        {
            System.out.println(ie);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Please help me out how to read the first word of every line and write that word to another file.

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: If you use Java 7, use `Files`!

Comment: @colti.. Garbage Output. it goes in infinite loop..

Comment: @fge.. thats what i am using..

Comment: Errr, are you sure? See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the program for you to read the first word of every line from a file and then writes into another file. This is not a perfect program but it works and it at least should give a starting point.

```
String separator = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
                 BufferedReader br;
                 String line;
                 InputStream fis = null;
                 File file = new File("C:\\junk\\out.txt");
                    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                 try
                 {
                     //your input file
                     fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\junk\\test.txt");
                     br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                     while((line = br.readLine())!=  null)
                     {
                         System.out.println(line);
                         String result[] = line.split(" ");
                         String word = result[0];
                         bw.write(word);
                         bw.write(separator);
                     }    
                 }

                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     System.out.println(e);
                 }

                 finally
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         //close the files
                         fis.close();
                        bw.close();
                     }
                     catch(IOException ie)
                     {
                         System.out.println(ie);
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: @stupefy welcome, feel free to give 1+ for this answer. happy I could help.

Answer (score 1):

AM not sure this is the best method you can split each line like this example:

```
String hello = "Hello world, How is everyone";
String[] split= hello.split(" ");
String first = split[0];

........
```

Then write it to the file using BufferedWriter like this:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("MyFIle.txt"));

bw.write(first);
bw.newLine();

bw.close();
```

This is just a guide.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor: use `Files`.

Obtaining a `BufferedReader` to a file is as simple as:

```
final BufferedReader reader 
    = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("pathToFile"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Obtaining a `BufferedWriter` is as simple as:

```
final BufferedWriter writer
    = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("pathToFile"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Reading all lines from a file is as simple as:

```
final List<String> lines 
    = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("pathToFile"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Etc etc. See [the javadoc for Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/file/Files.html). Anyone using Java 7 has no reason to use `File` anymore!